# Research in random forest algorithms able to switch data sets

Tags: random-forest, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I'm curious as to whether research been done into random forests that combine unsupervised with supervised learning in a way allowing a single algorithm to find patterns in, and work with, multiple different data sets. I have googled every possible way to find research on this, and have come up empty. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Semi-Supervised Learning**

The combination of unsupervised learning and supervised learning is referred to as **`semi-supervised learning`**, which is the concept that I believe you are searching for.

[`Label propagation`](http://www.slideshare.net/dav009/label-propagation-semisupervised-learning-with-applications-to-nlp) is often cited when outlining the heuristics of `semi-supervised learning`.  The essence is to employ clustering, but to use a tiny set of known cases in order to derive (or propogate) the labels of the clusters.  Hence one is able to use a small set of labeled cases to classify a much larger set of unsupervised data.

**Here are some references:**

- [Wikipedia has an entry on the `semi-supervised learning`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning).
- [The scikit learn User Guide is often a useful starting point and has a label propogation routine](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/label_propagation.html).
- There are, in fact, papers treating [`semi-supervised` `random forest` models](http://www.icg.tugraz.at/publications/pdf/srf.pdf).
- [Another one here](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/155552/decisionForests_MSR_TR_2011_114.pdf)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is genius!  Thank you so much.  I am new to data science (as a university student) and I had no idea where to start to learn for myself.  Those links are perfect.